# What is the meaning of 50 in command ">mean(c(1:10, 50))"

Tags: r, mean, outliers

I have tried it by using different numbers in place of 50 and got different answers. Please can anyone tell me the calculation of this number.

Comment: Check the output for this: `c(1:10, 50)` and this `c(1:10, 20)`, without mean. [`c`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html)

Comment: `c` is one of the first functions shown in every R introduction.

Comment: To expand on what Arpi said, if you don't understand what something does first try looking at what the components do. In this case it's just extracting what's inside the outer parentheses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "calculation" behind this number. Quite simply, [`c()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/c.html) creates a vector:

```
> c(1:10, 50)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 50
```

and [`mean()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/mean.html) returns the [mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean#Arithmetic_mean_.28AM.29) of this vector (the sum divided by the length). If you vary the number, the mean also varies.

In statistics, a number like 50 here is known as an [outlier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier). One way to obtain an average (or, formally, a *measure of central tendency*) that's robust to outliers is by computing the [median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median):

```
> median(c(1:10, -100))
[1] 5
> median(c(1:10, 50))
[1] 6
> median(c(1:10, 5000))
[1] 6
```

Compare this with the means of the same vectors:

```
> mean(c(1:10, -100))
[1] -4.090909
> mean(c(1:10, 50))
[1] 9.545455
> mean(c(1:10, 5000))
[1] 459.5455
```

This example shows how a single outlying observation can greatly affect the mean but not the median.